# prime generator optimization

Tags: php, math, optimization

I'm starting out my expedition into Project Euler. And as many others I've figured I need to make a prime number generator. Problem is: PHP doesn't like big numbers. If I use the standard [Sieve of Eratosthenes function](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#PHP), and set the limit to 2 million, it will crash. It doesn't like creating arrays of that size. Understandable.

So now I'm trying to optimize it. One way, I found, was to instead of creating an array with 2 million variable, I only need 1 million (only odd numbers can be prime numbers). But now it's crashing because it exceeds the maximum execution time...

```
function getPrimes($limit) {
$count = 0;
for ($i = 3; $i < $limit; $i += 2) {
    $primes[$count++] = $i;
}

for ($n = 3; $n < $limit; $n += 2) {
    //array will be half the size of $limit
    for ($i = 1; $i < $limit/2; $i++) {
        if ($primes[$i] % $n === 0 && $primes[$i] !== $n) {
            $primes[$i] = 0;
        }
    }
}

return $primes;
}
```

The function works, but as I said, it's a bit slow...any suggestions?

One thing I've found to make it a bit faster is to switch the loop around.

```
foreach ($primes as $value) {
    //$limitSq is the sqrt of the limit, as that is as high as I have to go
    for ($n = 3; $n = $limitSq; $n += 2) {
        if ($value !== $n && $value % $n === 0) {
            $primes[$count] = 0;
            $n = $limitSq; //breaking the inner loop
        }
    }
    $count++;
}
```

And in addition setting the time and memory limit (thanks Greg), I've finally managed to get an answer. phjew.

Comment: I don't know if they are available in PHP, but I prefer bit sets to represent primes, as they are more compact.

Comment: There's a reason why you don't see any if's or % operations in the inner loop of the function at the Rosetta Code site: you don't need them. Get rid of them and the performance will greatly improve. I have blogged about this:

http://numericalrecipes.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/prime-numbers-2-the-sieve-of-erathostenes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Algorithmist's proposed solution](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/SPOJ_PRIME1)

> This is a modification of the standard
>   Sieve of Eratosthenes. It would be
>   highly inefficient, using up far too
>   much memory and time, to run the
>   standard sieve all the way up to n.
>   **However, no composite number less than
>   or equal to n will have a factor
>   greater than sqrt{n},
>   so we only need to know all primes up
>   to this limit**, which is no greater
>   than 31622 (square root of 10^9). This
>   is accomplished with a sieve. **Then,
>   for each query, we sieve through only
>   the range given, using our
>   pre-computed table of primes to
>   eliminate composite numbers**.

This problem has also appeared on UVA's and Sphere's online judges. [Here's how it's enunciated on Sphere.](https://www.spoj.pl/problems/PRIME1/)

Comment: Without knowing the details of the problem:
this collection of primes even suffices for factorizing numbers up to 10^9. Suppose you start with a number X, divide out some prime factors, and have Y left. Try primes until sqrt(Y) (no further, this is useless!). If you find nothing, Y is prime, and you're done factorizing. So: if you know all primes up to some number A, you can factorize all numbers up to A^2.

Comment: I'll just mark this as the answer, as it was the resource that helped me the most. I found most answers here to be good and helpful, though (:

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing much about the algorithm:

1. You're recalculating `$limit/2` each time around the $i loop
2. Your if statement will be evaluated in order, so think about (or test) whether it would be faster to test `$primes[$i] !== $n` first.

Side note, you can use [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/set_time_limit) to give it longer to run and give it more memory using

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

Assuming your setup allows this, of course - on a shared host you may be restricted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a bit field to store your sieve.  That is, it's roughly identical to an array of booleans, except you pack your booleans into a large integer.  For instance if you had 8-bit integers you would store 8 bits (booleans) per integer which would further reduce your space requirements.

Additionally, using a bit field allows the possibility of using bit masks to perform your sieve operation.  For example, if your sieve kept all numbers (not just odd ones), you could construct a bit mask of b01010101 which you could then AND against every element in your array.  For threes you could use three integers as the mask: b00100100 b10010010 b01001001.

Finally, you do not need to check numbers that are lower than `$n`, in fact you don't need to check for numbers less than `$n*$n-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you know the number is not a prime, I would exit the enter loop.  I don't know php, but you need a statement like a break in C or a last in Perl.

If that is not available, I would set a flag and use it to exit the inter loop as a condition of continuing the interloop.  This should speed up your execution as you are not checking $limit/2 items if it is not a prime.

Comment: Why would you exit the loop? Say that $n is currently set to 3, when I then get to value 9, I don't want to exit, I want to find the rest of the numbers that are factors of 3, don't I?

Answer (score 0):

if you want speed, don’t use PHP on this one :P

no, seriously, i really like PHP and it’s a cool language, but it’s not suited at all for such algorithms

Comment: if the algorithm is well designed, it doesn't matter if it's written on php. Sphere's online judge has records on the people who have solved this very same problem on php.